# `graph-tool` edge bundling circular layout graph from weighted adjacency block matrix

Tags: python, networkx, graph-visualization, graph-tool, digraphs

I am trying [`graph-tool`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6wgAD.png) by Tiago Peixoto to build a graph (either directed or undirected) from a given weighted adjacency matrix with a block structure. So far, unsuccessfully. My question partly overlaps with [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66062025/circular-layout-with-edge-bundling-and-labels-in-graph-tool) on SO, which, however, remains without a clear solution.

Suppose I have a function that generates my block matrix of weights **J**, which is in the form:

[image]

Each block **J<sub>ij</sub>** is some random binary matrix with entries drawn from a given distribution. The scalars *s* and *g* respectively denote weights for connections within diagonal blocks (i.e. when *i = j*) and blocks off the diagonal (i.e. *i ≠ j*).

I build my graph in `graph_tool` as follows:

```
import graph_tool.all as gt

directed = False  # True if we want the graph to be directed 
J = generate_adj_bmatrix(...,s=0.1,g=0.01,directed=directed) # Some function to generate the weighted adjacency matrix (here the matrix will be symmetric since we want the graph undirected)  

# Define graph
G = gt.Graph(directed=directed)
indexes = J.nonzero()
G.add_edge_list(np.transpose(indexes))
# Add weight information
G.ep['weight'] = G.new_ep("double", vals=J[indexes])
```

I can also add, if I want, some `VertexProperty` to my `G` graph to whose block my nodes belong. But how do I include this information in the code whereby I can build the circular graph? The code reads (pasted here from [graph-tool docs](https://graph-tool.skewed.de/static/doc/draw.html?highlight=draw_hierarchical#graph_tool.draw.draw_hierarchy)):

```
state = gt.minimize_blockmodel_dl(G) # or should I consider instead state = gt.minimize_nested_blockmodel_dl(G)?
gt.draw_hierarchy(state)
t = gt.get_hierarchy_tree(state)[0]
tpos = pos = gt.radial_tree_layout(t, t.vertex(t.num_vertices() - 1), weighted=True)
cts = gt.get_hierarchy_control_points(G, t, tpos)
pos = G.own_property(tpos)
b = state.levels[0].b
shape = b.copy()
shape.a %= 14    # Have not yet figured out what I need it for
gt.graph_draw(G, pos=pos, vertex_fill_color=b, vertex_shape=shape, 
              edge_control_points=cts,edge_color=[0, 0, 0, 0.3], vertex_anchor=0)
```

Noteworthy is that the above code currently hangs seemingly too long. The `minimize_blockmodel_dl(G)` line appears to engage in an endless loop. Ideally, I should not sample my graph for clusters, since this information could already be provided as a property to the vertexes, based on my knowledge of the block structure of **J**. At the same time, `minimize_blockmodel_dl(G)` seems necessary in order to access the edge bundling option, doesn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution I came up with.

```
def visualize_network(J,N_sizes):
"""
Visualize a network from weighted block adjacency matrix in a circular layout with FEB.

Input arguments:
-- J : Weighted adjacency matrix (in block-matrix form, but can be any, as far as it is square). 
-- N_sizes : {<block1_label>: size; <block2_label>: size,...} such that node indexes of block n follow immediately those of block n-1.  
"""

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors
import graph_tool.all as gt

# Generate the graph
G = gt.Graph(directed=True) # In my case, network edges are oriented
eindexes = J.nonzero()
G.add_edge_list(np.transpose(eindexes))
# Add weight information
weight = G.new_ep("double", vals = J[eindexes])

# Assign color to each vertex based on the block it belongs to 
colors = {'B1' : 'k',
          'B2' : 'r',
          'B3' : 'g',
          'B4' : 'b'}
regs = np.asarray(list(N_sizes.keys()))
rindexes = np.cumsum(list(N_sizes.values()))
iidd = regs[np.searchsorted(rindexes,np.arange(np.shape(J)[0]))]
region_id = G.new_vp("string",vals=iidd)
vcolors = [colors[id] for id in iidd]
vertex_color = G.new_vp("string",vals=vcolors)

# Assigns edge colors by out-node.
eid = regs[np.searchsorted(rindexes,np.arange(np.shape(J)[0]))]
ecolors = [mcolors.to_hex(c) for c in regs[np.searchsorted(rindexes,eindexes[0]]] 
edge_color = G.new_ep("string",vals=ecolors)

# Construct a graph in a circular layout with FEB
G = gt.GraphView(G, vfilt=gt.label_largest_component(G))
state = gt.minimize_nested_blockmodel_dl(G)
t = gt.get_hierarchy_tree(state)[0]
tpos = gt.radial_tree_layout(t, t.vertex(t.num_vertices() - 1, use_index=False), weighted=True)
cts = gt.get_hierarchy_control_points(G, t, tpos)
pos = G.own_property(tpos)

gt.graph_draw(G,
              pos = pos,
              vertex_fill_color = vertex_color,
              edge_control_points = cts,
              edge_color = edge_color,
              vertex_anchor = 0)
```

Additional documentation on the circular layout and this way of building the graph can be found at [this](https://graph-tool.skewed.de/static/doc/draw.html?highlight=get_hierarchy_control_points#graph_tool.draw.get_hierarchy_control_points) `graph-tool` doc page.